# load fasttext model and using GPU

Tags: nlp, google-colaboratory, fasttext

I want to use `cc.fa.300.bin` **FastText** model on **colab** and I want to make it use the colab **GPU** this is my code:

```
model_path = '/content/model/fasttext/cc.fa.300.bin'
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = fasttext.load_model(model_path, device, device=device)
```

Comment: Does that code even run? I don't see anything in the Facebook `fasttext` Python wrapper docs or source code that suggests the `.load_model()` method takes either a positional `device` parameter, or a named `device` parameter – much less both redundantly. Doesn't running this code give you an error about unexpected arguments?

Answer (score 1):

> fastText  is an open-source, free, lightweight library [...]. It works
> on **standard, generic hardware.**

It is not meant to run on GPU. In fact, it performs very well on CPU.

This [Github issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/451) confirms this and also points out that BlazingText (on Aws SageMaker)  is basically a proprietary GPU implementation/extension of fastText.